WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): [AxiosError: There is no suitable adapter to dispatch the request since
WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
[AxiosError: There is no suitable adapter to dispatch the request since :

adapter xhr is not supported by the environment
adapter http is not available in the build
adapter fetch is not supported by the environment]

this error is coming in my renative app , i have lg webos and android tv code in this repo am facing this issue from long time when am starting app for android tv


Use the Fetch API Directly
If Axios is incompatible, consider using the native fetch API, which is well-supported in most environments, including React Native.



fetch('https://example.com/api', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));




Use an Alternative Library
Consider using libraries like React Native's fetch or node-fetch, which might better suit your environment.

Force Axios to Use the Fetch Adapter
You can configure Axios to explicitly use a fetch-based adapter. Install the axios-fetch-adapter package:
npm install axios-fetch-adapter




import axios from 'axios';
import fetchAdapter from '@vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter';

const instance = axios.create({
  adapter: fetchAdapter,
});

instance.get('https://example.com/api')
  .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));




Add Polyfills
Ensure that the required APIs are available in your environment. Add polyfills for XMLHttpRequest or fetch if necessary:
npm install react-native-fetch-polyfill


In your index.js or entry file:
import 'react-native-fetch-polyfill';


Check Environment Setup
Verify the React Native configuration for your Android TV or LG WebOS project. Ensure that all required modules and APIs are supported.

Debug the Runtime Environment
Run this snippet to debug what APIs are available in your environment:



Your code snippets do not work. Are you sure you didn't just meant to format the code using a [code block]?
